# Nearest distance algorithm using Phalcon model manager

Tags: php, phalcon

I am trying to do a select statement to select the nearest location of my records based on the input lat / lng values. I am building my web app using phalcon framework.

I followed the query algo as taught in google map tutorial at https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3?csw=1 and have some issues trying to rebuild it using phalcon model manager.

The select statement from Google

```
SELECT id, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM markers HAVING distance < 25 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20;
```

This is what i have currently

```
$query = $this->modelsManager->createQuery("SELECT id, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(:locationlat:) ) * cos( radians( locationlat ) ) * cos( radians( locationlng ) - radians(:locationlng:) ) + sin( radians(:locationlat:) ) * sin( radians( locationlat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM Listing HAVING distance < 25;");

$listing = $query->execute(array(
    'locationlat' => '1.313022',
    'locationlng' => '1.313022',              
));
```

Note: in my table, each record has a locationlat, locationlng column (instead of lat/lng as shown in google tutorial)

I am hitting this error below which i have no idea on what is it.

```
Scanning error before '' when parsing: SELECT id, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(:locationlat:) ) * cos( radians( locationlat ) ) * cos( radians( locationlng ) - radians(:locationlng:) ) + sin( radians(:locationlat:) ) * sin( radians( locationlat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM Listing HAVING distance < 25; (259)
```

Any phalcon experts here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Semicolon in your PHQL query causes `Scanning error before ...` problem. Just remove it and query should be ok:

```
$query_text = "SELECT 
                 id, 
                 ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(:locationlat:) ) * cos ( radians( locationlat ) ) * cos( radians( locationlng ) - radians(:locationlng:) ) + sin( radians(:locationlat:) ) * sin( radians( locationlat ) ) ) ) AS distance 
               FROM 
                 Listing
               HAVING 
                 distance < 25";
                             ^^

$query = $this->modelsManager->createQuery($query_text);

$listing = $query->execute(array(
    'locationlat' => '1.313022',
    'locationlng' => '1.313022',              
));
```